# Binding ComboBox to DataTable That is not in Dataset

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, bindingsource

I am using Vb.Net to develop small application. I want to bind combobox to datatable that is not in dataset. Binding to dataset is as follows:

```
bsOS=new bindingSource(ds,"tablename")
```

Assume I created my own distinct table values as follows:

```
tblOS = dstaset.Tables("computers").DefaultView.ToTable(True, "os")
```

What I want to do is something like the following:

```
bsOS = New BindingSource(tblOS)
```

But this error comes:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.ComponentModel.IContainer'.
```

Is there away to do it without adding the table to a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Combobox.DataSource = tblOs
Combobox.ValueMember = "<Column name you want as value>"
Combobox.DisplayMember = "<Column name which value you want to display in the list>"
```

To update the DataSource values you can do something like this:

```
Dim tblOs as DataTable = Combobox.DataSource
Dim dr as DataRow = tblOs.NewRow()
dr.Item(0) = "value"
dr.Item(n) = "display"
```

Since your DataTable isn't bound to anything I doubt it is possible to get it to update automatically. However If you keep tblOs as a property, instead of a local variable, it will update the Combobox as soon as it gets a new row.